# Group overlap in R (market share/correlations)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have user-level data in R that shows different groups the user has interacted with. What I would like to figure out is the overlap between those groups. I have a sample of the data below:

```
Group UserID
A     User1
B     User1
D     User1
A     User2
```

As you can see, User1 has interacted with 3 groups, while User2 has only interacted with Group A. What I would like to find out is the "market share" of users each Group has. For example, it may turn out that Group A had 100,000 users who ONLY interacted with Group A, 10,000 who interacted with A&B, 5,000 who interacted with A,B, and C, etc. There are a lot of combinations obviously.

Is there a way to calculate this using tidyr/dplyr? There are ~1million users & 600 groups. Each user has the potential to interact with some groups but not all.

Thank you!

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: 2 column data frame. Example: A: 10,000, A & B: 5,000, A & B & C: 1,000, B: 11,000, B & C: 1000, etc. Essentially 1 row for every combination. I misspoke on my initial post - not all users can interact with every group, so it should come out to around 200,000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to know the number of other interactions this will work:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "B", "D", "A", "C", "D", "D", "B", "C"),
                 UserID = c("User1", "User1", "User1", "User2", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5", "User5"))


library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group, UserID) %>% # make sure there are no double entries
  summarise() %>%             # make sure there are no double entries
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  mutate(NGroups = n()) %>%   # how many interactions has this user
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Group, NGroups) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>%      # count for each Group - NInteractions combination the frequency
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = NGroups, values_from = N)
```

If you want the count for each individual combination of groups, this should get you started ;) :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group, UserID) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  mutate(GroupsString = paste0(Group, collapse="")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Group, GroupsString) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```